# Custom operators in Bison/Yacc

Tags: c++, bison, yacc

Is there a way to introduce custom operators (defined in the scanner with a regex) with precedence? As far as I know, this cannot be done with %prec or other bison possibilities, so the way is to use std::map or something else. But how to tell Bison that this precedence has to be checked?

Comment: Do you mean that you would like to attach a precedence to the operator at runtime?

Comment: Yes, like this, have a number of predefined operators, but also the possibility to create custom ones.

Comment: Do you require the custom operator to be declared before it is used?

Comment: @rici Of course, yes (either with fixed precedence for all custom operators or assignable)